# Issues with pandastable and tkinter in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pandas, tkinter

I'm having issues importing pandastable using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import Tkinter
import pandastable

ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I then try the following hack which I read:

```
import sys
sys.modules['tkinter'] = Tkinter
import pandastable

ImportError: No module named ttk
```

I then import ttk and import pandastable again, but still get `ImportError: No module named ttk`

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: It looks like Pandas wants to use the Python3 names for Tk.  `ttk` is under `tkinter.ttk` on python3... what if you did `sys.modules['tkinter.ttk'] = ttk`?

Comment: What version of python are you running.  I know you tagged as python2, but it would be nice if you showed the output of `python --version`.

Comment: when i import pandastable after sys.modules['tkinter.ttk'] = ttk, I get ImportError: cannot import name filedialog.

sys.version: '2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Answer (score 0):

Pandastable requires python 3. From the project page:

> Python 3 compatible only since upgrading tkinter applications breaks
>   too much for backwards compatibility. For a similar table widget that
>   works in Python 2 see the previous incarnation, tkintertable.

See https://code.google.com/p/pandastable/